# GitLab Job fails on different (docker) runner with the same image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm, cicd

We are generally running GitLab with our own Kubernetes runners setup via the helm-chart. For special jobs, we want to use a VM with ubuntu 22.04lts, dind rights and more power. The setup worked and jobs using the inital default image we set `python:3.11-alpine` are running as expected. However, other job fails with some seamingly random file not found errors.
For example, yaml-lint fails with this error:

```
Using docker image sha256:68d3b7d6ad2e3001699585e293d0458ca50cd2b2703a3411bcb88f5f56184f43 for cytopia/yamllint:latest with digest cytopia/yamllint@sha256:3e9eb827ab2b12a5ea5f49d4257bb3aca94bba9f1ba427c8bc7f2456385a5204 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yamllint", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/yamllint/cli.py", line 208, in run
    conf = YamlLintConfig(file=args.config_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/yamllint/config.py", line 41, in __init__
    with open(file) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'if [ -x /usr/local/bin/bash ]; then\n\texec /usr/local/bin/bash \nelif [ -x /usr/bin/bash ]; then\n\texec /usr/bin/bash \nelif [ -x /bin/bash ]; then\n\texec /bin/bash \nelif [ -x /usr/local/bin/sh ]; then\n\texec /usr/local/bin/sh \nelif [ -x /usr/bin/sh ]; then\n\texec /usr/bin/sh \nelif [ -x /bin/sh ]; then\n\texec /bin/sh \nelif [ -x /busybox/sh ]; then\n\texec /busybox/sh \nelse\n\techo shell not found\n\texit 1\nfi\n\n'
```

For a selenium job we get multiple `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc.139824642997424'` and finally `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` when trying to install the pip dependencies.

We tried chaning the `config.toml` and changed the default image, but the error stays the same. Is it possible that paths are different when running docker in Kubernetes instead of the VM docker setup?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to uninstall docker (snap package) and install it again via `apt`. Would still be interesting to know why this works and the snap package has influence on the rights inside the container.